# Exposing correct factory classes to lua

Tags: c++, inheritance, lua, abstract-class, luabridge

So I am writing a factory system to create objects and using lua to call them. however I am struggling to figure out how to expose them to lua using luaBridge.

I have a template factory:

```
    template <class T, class Id>
    {
         T* create(Id name)
         {
         }
         void register(Id name, BaseCreator<T>* func)
         }
         }
         std::map<Id, Creator<T>*> FunctionMap;
     }
```

The register function calls a inherited template create class that is derived from a virtual create to create objects of a certain type that is derived from a base object.

```
    class BaseObject{virtual void hello() = 0;}
    class DerivedObject : public BaseObject{void hello()}

    template <class T> class BaseCreator { virtual T*create = 0; }

    template <class Base, class derived> 
    class DerivedCreator 
    { 
           Base* create () 
           { 
                 return new derived; 
            }
     }
```

In C++ the factory is used like this:

```
     Factory<DerivedObject, string> objMap;
     objmap.register("Obj1", new DerivedCreator<DerivedObject, BaseObject>;
     BaseObject * Temp = objMap.create("obj1");
```

Do I have to expose the virtual base classes like BaseObject and BaseCreator to lua in order for me to create their derived types using lua? I have tried this and I get an error about creating an abstract object. Is there a way around this if I do have to expose the bass classes or is there another scripting language more suitable to handling this task?

Comment: How do you use factories in Lua code? Are there several factories creating different object types?
I am asking because I doubt that you have to use both dynamic and static polymorphism at the same time.